# Cognito OAuth2 userId validation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, amazon-cognito

I've got a Spring Boot application where I currently am integrated with Amazon Cognito in order to validate auth tokens. This is currently working, but at this moment any caller of the API can provide a user_id to perform operations, and that user_id might not match with the auth token that was provided. This scenario is not handled properly.

I would like to be able to validate that the auth token belongs to that specific user_id that's being passed. How can this be achieved?

This is my SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity // Enable Spring Security’s web
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true) // To configure method-level security
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .requiresChannel(channel ->
                        channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(expressionInterceptUrlRegistry -> expressionInterceptUrlRegistry
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And my `application.properties`

```
aws.access-key=xxxxxxxxx
aws.access-secret=xxxxxxxxxxx
aws.cognito.clientId=xxxxxxxxx
aws.cognito.userPoolId=xxxxxxxxxx
aws.cognito.region=xxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx

...
```

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

I am aware of Cognito's `/oauth2/userInfo` (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html)), but I am not sure how to use it nor do I think it can integrate easily and elegantly into my existing auth solution (which is very simple, to say the least)

Comment: If the expected user_id is a claim in the JWT, then you could add a custom filter to the chain that checks that the API call's user_id matches the user_id claim in the JWT.

Comment: I see... How can I do that? And is there anything that has to be configured in Cognito to make this a thing?

Comment: It looks like you figured it out from your answer. However, one thing to consider with your AuthenticationService approach is that you must remember to call it at the start of each API method. That may introduce boilerplate, be error-prone, and tightly couple auth with the implementation of your rest controller. You could alternatively implement the logic in the AuthenticationService as a custom filter and add it to the SecurityFilterChain so that Spring Security can return a 401/403 before a rest controller method is ever invoked.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that! The problem is the user_id provided by the API caller is given as a query param, so I wasn't really sure if it made sense to abstract it for every endpoint 

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone. It looks like my initial `SecurityConfig` code already has everything that would be needed in order to get the user_id out of the JWT token. This is accessible through the `SecurityContextHolder` (see code below). `"sub"` is the claim that seems to have the user_id.

In the end, I ended up solving it by creating an `AuthenticationService`, then calling it first thing when executing one of the methods in my controller.

```java
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {
    public void authenticate(String userId) {
        Jwt authToken = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String authenticatedUserId = (String) authToken.getClaims().get("sub");

        if (authenticatedUserId == null || !authenticatedUserId.equals(userId)) {
            throw new HttpUnauthorizedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SpEL in `@PreAuthorize` expression:

```java
@GetMapping("/users/{userSubject}")
@PreAuthorize("authentication.name == #userSubject")
public SomeDto getUserById(@PathVariable("userSubject") String userSubject) {
    ...
}
```

This should work because with Spring Security

- the default authentication converter for resource servers with JWT decoder uses the `sub` claim to set `JwtAuthenticationToken#name`
- `authentication` in SpEL binds to the Authentication instance in the SecurityContext
- `#userSubject` in SpEL binds to the parameter named `userSubject` in the method it decorates

You can change the claim used in the token to set `JwtAuthenticationToken#name`. For that, you'll have to provide with a custom `Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken>` in your security configuration with `http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(myAuthenticationConverter)));`.

With the same converter, you'll be able to map `cognito:groups` (or any other claim) to spring authorities, to enhance the expression above to things like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin') || authentication.name == #userSubject")
```

For more details, as well as tips to work with the fact that Cognito allows to set custom private claims only to ID tokens, refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).